# JFace - Remove keyboard focus from dialog

Tags: java, jface

I have a `ProgressMonitorDialog` object which contains a `cancel` button.  I want to disable the initial focus of the `cancel` button.  The reason I want to remove the initial focus from the button is that a user may accidentally hit a key on the keyboard while a batch operation is in progress and cancel the whole operation.  If a user wants to cancel an operation I would prefer that they press the tab key and manually set the focus, or click on the `cancel` button with a mouse.

From what I can tell, there is no easy way to do this.  I can create another button on the `ProgressMonitorDialog` that does nothing and have that take focus, but that's an ugly workaround. Especially since the button has to be visible or the focus will shift to the `cancel` button. I have also tried overriding the method that creates the `cancel` button and bypassing the `shell.setDefaultButton()` method but no luck.

Any clues/suggestions?

Comment: An alternative would be to override `cancelPressed` and show an 'are you sure' prompt before allowing the cancel.

Comment: The only downside I see to that is the 'are you sure' prompt would also have buttons in focus. Let's say a user accidentally is holding down the space bar.  Setting the focus to cancel on the prompt would cause it to go back to the original cancel button, causing a loop. Setting the focus to 'ok' would be the same as not having a secondary prompt

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending Dialog class, then you can do the following, override createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite) method, and pass in false as default button argument on the button which you don't want the initial focus on.

```
         @Override
        protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
            // create OK and Cancel buttons by default
            createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, false);
            createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
         }
```